# Unable to ssh in to machine behind router

Tags: ssh, sshd, port-forwarding

I'm trying to ssh into a desktop which is behind a router from a remote location.  I've set the router (TP-link AC1750) to forward TCP connections to port 8000 along to port 8000 on my desktop using it's local network IP.  (I'm following advice I read on a number of pages and not using the default port 22).  I've included

```
Port 8000
```

in my desktop's sshd_config file so that it listens for requests on port 8000.

When I then try to ssh in from a remote machine with

```
ssh -p 8000 username@routers-public-ip-address
```

I get a timeout error.  Running

```
ssh -p -v username@routers-public-ip-address
```

on the client side gives

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to <ip address> [<ip address>] port 8000
debug1: connect to address 128.253.10.57 port 8000: Operation timed out
ssh: connect to host 128.253.10.57 port 8000: Operation timed out
```

The server side logs have no indication that an attempt at a TCP connection was made.

I have no trouble ssh'ing in from a computer on the same LAN using my local IP.

I'm trying to find the logs on the router itself, as I now suspect that's where the problem is, given that the server doesn't appear to have any log of an attempted connection.  Once I can find those, if it doesn't immediately solve the problem I'll update this post again.

Comment: why do you try to ssh to port 8584, if you set up your router to forward port 8000 ? you should try ssh -p 8000 ....

Comment: Sorry, I was using -p 8000.  Just corrected the question.

Comment: Why not just try with default 22 to get it working, then change the ports?

Comment: When you say _pings_ do you really mean _TCP connections_, as that is what you really want. You will find `-v` option (can be specified multiple times to increase verbosity) a useful debugging tool on the client side. On the server side check logs or kill your original daemon and run `sshd -D` at command line to see more useful server side messages.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I was using pings incorrectly - I edited the question.  I am trying to forward TCP connections.

Comment: I've updated my post with the output of ssh -v from the client side and the server side logs.  I've also tried using port 22 for now, which also was unsuccessful.  Once I can find the relevant logs from the router after a connection attempt I can post those as well.  Thanks again to all for the helpful comments.

Comment: Maybe your ISP is intentionally blocking any HTTP-like ports like 80, 8080, 8008, 8000 and others that often used by default configured routers? Try to use random port from 32768 and up. And use public port check services like ping.eu to quickly test if your port is open.